# Vim - Step through search and replace results

Tags: vim

Is it possible to step through the **results** of a search and replace to ensure that no unwanted modifications were made to your code in a boldly-executed, entire-file search and replace?

Vim throws up the status message:

```
"*X* substitutions on *Y* lines"
```

and I'm curious if there's a  key or command to step through each of those substitutions and do a quick check to make sure you haven't shot yourself in the foot with an unexpected string match. I am new to Vim.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

From http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Search_and_replace,

```
:%s/foo/bar/gc
    Change each 'foo' to 'bar', but ask for confirmation first.
```

Comment: Aha!  It was terribly obvious!  I must have skimmed right over this in my brief search for an answer; I was definitely on that wiki page.  Thanks a bunch :)

Answer (score 1):

This is how you should have found that info yourself, without Google, the Vim wiki or SO:

1. Look for help on the `:substitute` command:

   ```
   :help :s
   ```
2. Read the paragraph and notice the part where it talks about optional `[flags]`:

   ```
   :[range]s[ubstitute]/{pattern}/{string}/[flags] [count]
       [...
       skipped lines
       ...]
       See |:s_flags| for [flags].
   ```
3. Hit `<C-]>` on the highlighted `:s_flags`.
4. Hooooo…